# A Django admin interface for my Django admin interface

Tags: django, design-patterns, django-models, django-admin, subclassing

My Django project has models `ShopType` and `ShopItem`. For each `ShopType` object I create, I want to associate — not a single `ShopItem` object — but a *subclass* of `ShopItem`. Basically, I want a model type in Django that is not a TextField or an ImageField or the like, but a *Model*Field.

Example: Using the Django admin interface, I create a new instance of `ShopType` called `CheeseShop`. This in turn creates a new Model called `Cheese` which inherits all of its behavior from `ShopItem`. If I go to the main page of my Django admin site, there's now a new link called "Cheeses", and I can create a bunch of `Cheese`s as I please.

Of course, I suspect that's not actually possible: If I create — say — `PetShop`, I wouldn't just have to add a new record to the database, I'd have to augment the database schema itself to include `Pet`s (along with registering the new `Pet` Model with the admin interface and probably some other complicated things I haven't thought of yet).

But maybe there's an existing Django solution for this pattern? Or maybe there's a completely different, better-suited approach to the problem that might achieve the same effect?

Any thoughts?